# RollingFileAppender not picking up ThreadContext map entries for setting filename

Tags: logging

Java Class

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LogsTest123 {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogsTest123.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LogsTest123 logsTest123 = new LogsTest123();
        logsTest123.check();
    }

    private void check() {
        ThreadContext.put("identifier", "threadcontext value");
        logger.info("sjdoe");
    }

}
```

Log4j configuration which I am using :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="devToolServices"
    packages="com.bidgely.cloud.utils.log4j2">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseDir">coding/logs
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/portUser-$${ctx:identifier}.log"
            filePattern="${baseDir}/portUser-$${ctx:identifier}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.%i">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%h - [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] - %C:%M:%L - %t - %p -$${ctx:identifier} : %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="24"
                    modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Log files generated are ***portUser-${ctx:identifier}.log***. Placeholder is not being replaced by the threadcontext map value.
Content of log file has threadcontext map value "threadcontext value"
10.10.0.143 - [2018-04-21 14:01:15,544] - com.devtools.dataSync.LogsTest123:check:18 - main - INFO -threadcontext value : sjdoe

Comment: I have the same issue when setting Logger properties which, according to the documentation, should be added to the thread context map. Maybe ctx property resolution doesn't work for filenames in log4j2. I couldn't find any documentation regarding this limitation though.

Comment: I've reported my issue as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2799

Comment: I've got a response. This is not possible. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2799?focusedCommentId=17051354&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17051354

Answer (score 0):

You need to reconfigure the logger with it's context. So all appenders are recreated and updated with the new values.

Therefore use this code right after setting the ThreadContext variable to get the current logger context and update it.

```
final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
ctx.reconfigure();
```

Comment: not able to get thread context variable even after reconfiguring loggerContext as suggested by @jdickel.